# numpy equivalent of tf.math.segment_sum

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

What is the equivalent of [tf.math.segment_sum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_sum) in numpy?
So basically I like to rewrite the exact same code in tf to np where I am using segment sum to group together certain elements using a segment_ids array and sum those segments. What is the equivalent code in numpy? I have an array and the segment_ids array and I like to perform segment_sum but in numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create something pretty close to [`tf.math.segment_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_sum) with the method `numpy.add.at`, which is the [`at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method of the `add` ufunc:

```
def segment_sum(data, segment_ids):
    data = np.asarray(data)
    s = np.zeros((np.max(segment_ids)+1,) + data.shape[1:], dtype=data.dtype)
    np.add.at(s, segment_ids, data)
    return s
```

For example,

```
In [53]: c = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [54]: ids = [0, 0, 1]

In [55]: segment_sum(c, ids)
Out[55]: 
array([[5, 5, 5, 5],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [56]: x = [10, 20, 20, 30, 10, 0, 1, 2]

In [57]: xids = [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3]

In [58]: segment_sum(x, xids)
Out[58]: array([50, 30, 11,  2])

In [59]: w = np.arange(72).reshape(6, 2, 6) % 5

In [60]: w
Out[60]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1]],

       [[2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3]],

       [[4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
        [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2]],

       [[3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1]]])

In [61]: wids = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]

In [62]: segment_sum(w, wids)
Out[62]: 
array([[[2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 2],
        [4, 6, 3, 5, 2, 4]],

       [[4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]],

       [[4, 7, 5, 8, 6, 4],
        [7, 5, 8, 6, 4, 7]]])
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply! This is definitely the answer! Only change would be to take the remaining shape of data to deal with multi dimensions in segment_ids

```
def segment_sum(data, segment_ids):
    data = np.asarray(data)
    num_segments = np.max(segment_ids) + 1
    s = np.zeros((num_segments,) + data.shape[len(segment_ids.shape):], dtype=data.dtype)
    np.add.at(s, segment_ids, data)
    return s
```